# How to create two editor panes for the same file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I usually have a vertical split with two editor panes next to each other. Is there a way to have the same file in both of these panes?

Comment: Do you intend to have both panels synchronized? i.e both panels show class A, when you change panel 1 to class B the view in panel 2 will also change to class B?
It's possible currently (v9) to do it manually with a Go To Class in each panel.

Comment: Go To / Class will just focus on the already open tab that contains the file.

Comment: Window > Editor Tabs > Split Vertically in IDEA 13.1.6 (thought to mention since it seems to have moved)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

## Alt-Shift-Enter

In the 'Open File' or 'Go To Class' dialog, or Project view, press `Alt-Shift-Enter` (instead of just `Enter`) to have the selected file open in the current pane even if it's already open in another pane.

`Shift-Enter` will open the file in a floating window.

### Older versions of IntelliJ

In older versions of IntelliJ (maybe before IntelliJ 2016): this shortcut was just `Shift-Enter`.

### Newer versions of IntelliJ (2019.2)

`Shift-Enter`

Comment: Not sure this answer is still accurate for IntelliJ 14. When I hit shift-enter it opens the file in a floating window. Maybe I have remapped this keystroke in my keymap...looking into it...

Comment: In IntelliJ 2017.2.5, this opens the file in a floating window, like @Michael mentioned. I suspect the functionality has just changed over time. This still achieves what I was looking for with being able to open a second pane for the same file, though.

Comment: Alt-Shift-Enter seems to do it now

Comment: how do I toggle between the two files using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Does not work in IDEA 2022.3.3 on MacOs

Answer (score 87):

### IntelliJ IDEA 15

#### 3 approaches

1. **Right click** on the file **tab** > **Split Vertically** / **Split Horizontally**

   [image: Split Vertically]
2. Being in the file that you want to split, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > type "Split Vertically" / "Split Horizontally" > <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   [image: Action Split Vertically]
3. Being in the file that you want to split, **Window** > **Editor Tabs** > **Split Vertically** / **Split Horizontally**

   [image: Window Editor Tabs Split]

Answer (score 27):

It's possible in IntelliJ 10. First, use "Window -> Split Vertically" like Mr Rothgiesser suggests; this will open the same file in two panes in your single window. But then, to get it in a separate window, click and drag the tab from the newly-created pane off the original window into its own space on the desktop (that sounds more complicated than it is--just drag the tab off the window).

The file is now open in both windows, synchronized just as Mr Midwood suggests.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.If you have only one file open and then click "Window > Split Vertically", you get the same file on both sides. At least in IntelliJ IDEA 6.0.

Comment: Te same in 7.0.5. But it's not neccessary to have only one file open. The current shown tab will be shown in the new view.

Comment: That kind of works, almost. Since I already have a vertical split, I'd certainly prefer not to open a third pane.

Answer (score 3):

### IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2

Right click on the file tab > `Split Right` / `Down`

Answer (score 2):

Press **Shift-Ctrl-Enter** if you use IdeaVim and want same file get opened in an active tab group.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'm afraid it's not possible in the recent IDEA versions. Please vote for [IDEA-34593](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-34593) or watch this issue for progress to get a notification when the issue is resolved.</s>

**UPDATE**: As the issue was fixed, it's possible since IDEA 10, see the [reply from MattLeidholm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846565/how-to-create-two-editor-windows-for-the-same-file/5796002#5796002).

Comment: It is possible, see answer by LinkTiger.